# Disable line break's highlight/selection in textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea

How do I prevent the selection of line breaks inside a `<textarea>`?
It's an annoying thing that I can't find the solution for to change/customize.

My code is simply `<textarea></textarea>` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z3yc0yoo/)).

Image with **expected result** and **default look**:

[image: Textarea line break selection]

I'm trying to do it using javascript.
My browser is Chrome.

Comment: What's annoying about it?

Comment: @Midas The highlight of the line break that looks like a space.

Comment: @Midas Try triple clicking on the first line. It doesn't select the newline character. But use Ctrl+A to select all, and that new line character is selected as if there is an extra space in the end. It gets a bit confusing, as it is mistaken for regular space. :/

Comment: @jitendragarg It depends on the implementation of the OS/browser. Generally double click selects a whole word and triple click selects a whole line (including the newline character). There is a difference between selecting all characters in a line vs selecting the whole line. This difference in selection is visual by the extra "space character".

Comment: I want to restrict the ability to select the new line character, making it impossible to see that visual "space character" in any way the user tries.

Comment: Annoying! http://i.imgur.com/hicxwJ5.png